# Jenkins pipeline script not running

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

For the below pipeline script, "Helo World" is not printing. And even node is not getting allocated.

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Example') {
            steps {
                echo 'Hello World'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Installed "Pipeline: Declarative" plugin (to run declarative Pipeline scripts) and this worked.

Comment: Thanks for that, I had the same issue!
The evil part about it is that the job just runs silently without complaing about the DSL
Installed the pipeline-model-definition plugin and now it works

Comment: This is an amazing solution. Thank you so much for posting!!!!

Comment: It's an amazing problem more than an amazing solution. Why is Jenkins just silently accepting syntax it doesn't recognize? Why does the documentation tell you to use declarative syntax without mentioning that you need a plugin to make it work?

Answer (score 2):

I noticed this happens when the "Built-in Node"(i.e. the Jenkins controller's built-in node) is disabled. Bring up the this node makes the build run in any/specific node

Comment: I have the same. Thank you for this advice. 
But strange behavior, because i manually set "agent { label: '' } " in my pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

Naveen, Could you try below

```
pipeline {
    agent {label '**Add agent name here**'} //ex: root
       stages {
           stage('Example'){
                 steps {
                       echo "Hello World"

                }    

          } 
    
    }
```

}

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply, we do not have an agent.