# Jenkins build immediately finish

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a pipeline written in Jenkins. When I run it, it's like finished Succes right away. And that's it..

For example:

```
pipeline {
    agent { any }
    stages {
        stage('build') {
            steps {
                echo "Hello World!"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**In steps** is only one: "Start of Pipeline - (no timing in block)"

**In console output:**

Started by <my_name>

[Pipeline] End of Pipeline

Finished: SUCCESS

Comment: You are not performing any actions inside the build stage so its logically correct ... What behavior are you expecting?

Comment: @SiddharthSeth Look here, in this article the creator has output in console output 

https://code-maven.com/jenkins-pipeline-hello-world

Comment: Try using agent { label 'master' } and it should work...

Comment: Related: [SO-71218985](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71218985/16586783)

Comment: @SiddharthSeth Warning: JENKINS-41339 probably bogus PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin:$MAVEN_HOME/bin:/opt/jdk1.8.0_91/bin:/opt/apache-maven-3.3.9/bin; perhaps you meant to use ‘PATH+EXTRA=/something/bin’?
process apparently never started in /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Testy

running Jenkins temporarily with -Dorg.jenkinsci.plugins.durabletask.BourneShellScript.LAUNCH_DIAGNOSTICS=true might make the problem clearer)
Post stage

Comment: Try using sh "Hello World!" instead and let us know

Comment: @SiddharthSeth same problem

Comment: @dawid Do you have the `Pipeline: Declarative` plugin installed? Related: [SO-71218985](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71247427/16586783)

Comment: @SiddharthSeth Yes, I have it installed. Pipeline: Declarative Version 2.2064.v5eef7d0982b_e

I have no ideas anymore and I really care about it 

:((

Comment: @SiddharthSeth you're suggesting that Jenkins will just ignore the `echo`?